# Hyperspectral Data in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, imagery

The public organization I work for has some archived hyperspectral data (.raw - radiance, non georectified). 
Has anyone processed hyperspectral data for consumption within ArcMap? If so, what sort of products have you created from the hyperspectral data?
I would like to see this information utilized somehow instead of sitting on the server collecting dust, so to speak.

Comment: Do you have access to ENVI? I know that software has a bunch of tools for processing hyper spectral data.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to ENVI, nor the ENVI extension for ArcGIS.
I have stumbled across an open source software called Opticks and will have to see if it will aid in creating some useable images.

Comment: This seems to be seeking a list of products that users have created from hyperspectral data which makes it too broad for focussed Q&A.